# Unwanted behavior when using insidetextorientation = 'radial' in plotly sunburst

Tags: r, plotly, sunburst-diagram

When using `insidetextorientation = 'radial'`, even in a very simple plotly sunburst chart, some of the labels are grossly displaced.

```
library(plotly)

my_labels <- c("A","B","C","AA","AB","AC","BA","BB","CA","CB","CC")
my_parents <- c("","","","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C")
my_values <- c(15,23,7,3,5,7,6,17,1,2,4)

plot_ly(labels = my_labels,parents = my_parents,values = my_values,type = 'sunburst',
branchvalues = 'total',insidetextorientation = 'radial')
```

[image: image1]

Notice the "B" and "BA" on the left are misplaced. Similar issues occur when zooming in on any of the parents and do not persist with `insidetextorientation = 'auto'`. Is there a way to fix this?
On the plotly community forum [the same question](https://community.plotly.com/t/plotly-sunburst-plot-text-orientation-error/39110) was asked 2 years ago, but not answered.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a great answer. It works, but when you click out of a parent so that everything is showing again, the plot has to stop moving before the labels will change back to the radial angles.

I've tried a lot of different ways to improve it. I think that letting Plotly package authors know is important; short of changing the code, I don't know of a better way to make this happen. The main problem is that the SVG paths that change when you enter and leave a parent are deleted and re-calculated. Any event that's attached is deleted at that point. (I tried both Plotly events and straight JS events.)

So instead of an event, it's on an interval. Every 100 milliseconds it checks to see if the labels need to be fixed.

```
plot_ly(labels = my_labels, parents = my_parents,
        values = my_values, type = 'sunburst',
        branchvalues = 'total', insidetextorientation = 'horizontal') %>% 
  htmlwidgets::onRender("function() {
                        pc = ['B', 'A', 'C', 'BB', 'BA', 'AC', 'AB', 'AA', 'CC', 'CB', 'CA'];
                        rpl = [0, -64, 28, -68, 28, -32, -80, 68, 40, 16, 4];
                        rx = /.*rotate\\((.*)\\)/g;
                        function fixer(){
                          tx = document.querySelectorAll('g > text');
                          if(tx.length === 11) {       /*not when clicking subgroups*/
                            for(i=0;i<tx.length;i++){
                              wh = tx[i].getAttribute('data-unformatted');
                              tr = tx[i].getAttribute('transform');
                              rot = /.*rotate\\((.*)\\)/g.exec(tr);
                              if(rot !== null){        /*if a text rotation is designated*/
                                if(rpl[pc.indexOf(wh)] !== Number(rot)) {
                                  rot = rot[1];
                                  if(Number(rot) !== rpl[i] && wh === pc[i]){ /*if angle does not match & label does*/
                                    beg = /(.*)rotate/.exec(tr)[1];      /*capture translate string*/
                                    xy = beg + 'rotate(' + rpl[i] + ')'; /*build new transform string*/
                                    tx[i].setAttribute('transform', xy); /*replace transform string with new*/
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                              if(rot === null && wh === pc[i]) {      /*if no rotation is present and label matches*/
                                str = tr + 'rotate(' + rpl[i] + ')';  /* build new transform string */
                                tx[i].setAttribute('transform', str); /*replace transform string with new*/
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                        setInterval(fixer, 100);}")  # check regularly! (every 100 ms)
```

I basically started with `onRender` set to just spit out the transform attribute for every label, so that I could get the order in which the labels appear (see `pc` in the JS) and the angles that the labels are placed at (see `rpl` in the JS). This was done while `insidetextorientation = 'radial'`. (I actually looked at all the text options: tangential, horizontal, auto, and radial.)

From there I tried MANY things to trigger the JS function `fixer`. In the end the only thing that was consistent enough for me to even share my work was using `setInterval`.

[image]

#### Update; Firefox friendly!

I really did try to figure this out for my initial answer. Here is the code without static arrays for the labels or angles. Let me know if you run into issues.

```
plot_ly(labels = my_labels, parents = my_parents,
        values = my_values, type = 'sunburst',
        branchvalues = 'total', insidetextorientation = 'horizontal') %>% 
  htmlwidgets::onRender("function(el, x) {
                        /* calculates the angles for each slice */
                        function angler (arVal, deg){ /* array of values in order; degrees each value unit*/
                          results = []; /* for storing the results */
                          theta = 0;    /* for cumulative angle */
                          for(k = 0; k < arVal.length; k++){
                            here = arVal[k] * deg;      /* units times degrees */
                            mrot = theta + (.5 * here); /* initial text angle */
                            if(mrot >= 90 && mrot < 270) {
                              mrot = mrot - 180;   /* don't put text upside down */
                            }
                            if(mrot >= 270 && mrot < 360){
                              mrot = mrot - 360;   /* don't put text upside down */
                            }
                            results[k] = mrot;
                            theta = theta + here; /* for the next loop */
                          }
                          return(results);
                        }
                        par = x.data[0].parents; /* collect the necessary data*/
                        val = x.data[0].values;
                        lab = x.data[0].labels;
                        parI = par.reduce((a, e, i) => { /*which rows have parents?*/
                          if (e == '') { a.push(i); };
                          return a;
                        }, []);                  /*in array a, if element e at pos i equates to ''*/
                        parC = par.reduce((a, e, i) => { /*which rows do NOT have parents?*/
                          if (e != '') { a.push(i); };
                          return a;
                        }, []);                 /*in array a, if element e at pos i equates to ''*/
                        alp = lab.map((i, j) => {return [i, val[j], par[j]]}); /* combine data */
                        palv = alp.filter((e, i) => parI.some(j => i === j)); /*parent array*/
                        calv = alp.filter((e, i) => parC.some(j => i === j)); /*children array*/
                        pvalS = palv.sort(function(a, b) {
                          return((a[1] > b[1]) ? -1 : ((a[1] == b[1]) ?  0 : 1));
                        })  /*parents sorted by values*/
                        parS = pvalS.map(function(j) {return j[0];}); /*extract ordered parents*/
                        csort = [];        /* for ordered kids array*/
                        for(i = 0; i < parS.length; i++){ /* sort children by parent and size*/
                          arr = calv.filter(j => parS[i].includes(j[2]));
                          arr1 = arr.map(function(w) {return w[1]}); /*get just values*/
                          arr2 = arr1.sort(function(a, b){ return b - a });
                          bld = [];
                          for(k = 0; k < arr2.length; k++) {
                            arr3 = arr.filter(j => arr2[k] == j[1]);
                            csort = csort.concat(arr3);
                          }
                        }
                                          /* get the order--- in reverse*/
                        cvo = csort.map(function(j){return j[1]});
                        cvov = Object.values(cvo).reverse();
                        pvo = pvalS.map(function(j) {return j[1];}); /*extract ordered parents' values*/
                        pvov = Object.values(pvo).reverse();
                        ctots = cvov.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0); /* 45 */
                        rotV = 360/ctots;                 /* 8 in this example */
                        kids = angler(cvov, rotV);        /* collect kids angles */
                        parents = angler(pvov, rotV);     /* collect parent angles */
                        kidS = csort.map(function(j) {return j[0];});     /* extract kid labels in order */
                        /*pc = ['B', 'A', 'C', 'BB', 'BA', 'AC', 'AB', 'AA', 'CC', 'CB', 'CA'];*/
                        pc = Object.values(parS).concat(Object.values(kidS));
                        /*rpl = [0, -64, 28, -68, 28, -32, -80, 68, 40, 16, 4];*/
                        rpl = parents.reverse().concat(kids.reverse());
                        rx = /.*rotate\\((.*)\\)/g;
                        function fixer(){
                          tx = document.querySelectorAll('g > text');
                          if(tx.length === 11) {       /*not when clicking subgroups*/
                            for(i=0;i<tx.length;i++){
                              wh = tx[i].getAttribute('data-unformatted');
                              tr = tx[i].getAttribute('transform');
                              rot = /.*rotate\\((.*)\\)/g.exec(tr);
                              if(rot !== null){        /*if a text rotation is designated*/
                                if(rpl[pc.indexOf(wh)] !== Number(rot)) {
                                  rot = rot[1];
                                  if(Number(rot) !== rpl[i] && wh === pc[i]){ /*if angle does not match & label does*/
                                    beg = /(.*)rotate/.exec(tr)[1];      /*capture translate string*/
                                    xy = beg + 'rotate(' + rpl[i] + ')'; /*build new transform string*/
                                    tx[i].setAttribute('transform', xy); /*replace transform string with new*/
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                              if(rot === null && wh === pc[i]) {      /*if no rotation is present and label matches*/
                                str = tr + 'rotate(' + rpl[i] + ')';  /* build new transform string */
                                tx[i].setAttribute('transform', str); /*replace transform string with new*/
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                        setInterval(fixer, 100);}")  # check regularly! (every 100 ms)
```

Comment: Oh wow. I finally got to test it and that is quite the elaborate solution. In my real usecase, the sunburst chart is inside a shiny dashboard, so the data changes dynamically. The order of the segments is easy to find out by sorting each layer by value. But the calculation of the rotation seems much more daunting since it depends  pretty much on every other value (and order thereof) in the chart. Is there a way to look up in the plotly source code how they are calculated there? Or is it possible to get them out of `onRender` automatically?

Comment: If there is, I couldn't find it. I even thought about recreating the Plotly min.js for this. I think that's what it would take. Did you notice that, at least for this chart, `horizontal` really had the best positioning, except for AA? (Which has everything to do with the 180-degree flip from AB.) If you look at `getRotationAngle` and `transformInsideText` inside the [sunburst js](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/traces/sunburst/plot.js), you'll see it's from the data transforms that are done for a pie plot.  When you go that in the pie plot JS, it's a lot!

Comment: When typing my answer, I lost everything I wrote. So some things I wrote you aren't here. (Sorry!) The label order is by the size of the parent, and their children by size. The parent order is BAC. All B children are first, in order by size, then A's kids, then C's. All of the children add up to 45. There are 360 degrees in a circle; 360/45 = 8. 8 degrees for the first chunk. Put the label in the middle (right-side up—it matters), 8/2 = 4 degrees. CB's angle is CA + CB, so 3 * 8 = 24, but to get to the middle, you need half of 2 * 8 (because CB = 2), so the angle is 16. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I ran out of room in my comment. Now that I've written all that, maybe I can do this all with JS... give me a minute (or hours, realistically).

Comment: Updated...but quirky. Let me know if you run into any issues. Something is getting interpreted incorrectly by RStudio, but the browser has no issue with it...

Comment: That is a stunning amount of work you have put into this. It depends on the browser. It does work in MS Edge of all things, but e.g. Firefox runs into the same issues as the preview in RStudio.
Sadly I have not managed to make it work within shiny in either browser, but maybe that's to do with how the plot is called? At the moment it simply looks like
`output$my_plot <- renderPlotly({plot_function(input$my_input)})` with the `plot_ly` function creating the figure as above and then calling `plotlyOutput("my_plot")` in the ui. I've played around with the placement, but with no success so far.

Comment: I think I figured out the issue with Firefox/RStudio. For some reason, the method I used to sort the labels wasn't working. Let me know if there's still an issue. If this still isn't working in your Shiny app, would you mind asking another SO question? That way you can add your Shiny code (or a skeleton of the code) so I can see what you're working with. It's hard to troubleshoot without any details. You can comment here with the link and I'll try to work on it as soon as I see it. (I dropped it in Shiny with no issues, so I need more info. We're approaching the comment limit here...