# Can I align a Plotly (Python) Sunburst label in the midpoint of the wedge?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, sunburst-diagram

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as io
import textwrap

wrap_width = 25
def customwrap(s,width=wrap_width): #Function responsible for wrapping text for the captions
    return "<br>".join(textwrap.wrap(s,width=width))

io.renderers.default='browser'

scope = ['Scope 1','Scope 1', 'Scope 2', 'Scope 2', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3',
 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3',
 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3', 'Scope 3']

component = ['Diesel (company vehicles)', 'Petrol (company vehicles)', 'Electricity for<br>appliances', 'Other Scope 2', 'Fuel- and energy-related<br>activities (FERA)', 'Upstream transportation<br>in operations', 
             'Other Scope 3', 'Other Scope 3','Employee commuting', 'Downstream transportation<br>and distribution', 'Use of sold products<br>(including indirect use)', 'End-of-life treatment of<br>sold products',
 'Purchased goods &<br>services', 'Purchased goods &<br>services', 'Purchased goods &<br>services', 'Purchased goods &<br>services', 'Purchased goods &<br>services', 'Purchased goods &<br>services', 'Purchased goods &<br>services', 'Purchased goods &<br>services',
 'Purchased goods &<br>services', 'Purchased goods &<br>services', 'Purchased goods &<br>services', 'Purchased goods &<br>services', 'Purchased goods &<br>services', 'Purchased goods &<br>services', 'Purchased goods &<br>services', 'Purchased goods &<br>services',
 'Purchased goods &<br>services', 'Purchased goods &<br>services', 'Purchased goods &<br>services', 'Purchased goods &<br>services', 'Purchased goods &<br>services', 'Purchased goods &<br>services', 'Purchased goods &<br>services']

other1 = [None, None, None, 'Other electricity usage', None, None, 'Waste generated in operations', 'Business travel', None, None, None, None, 'External services', 'Other', 'Component 3', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other',
 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Packaging 1', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Packaging 6', 'Other', 'Packaging 8']

other2 = [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Component 2', None, 'Component 4', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Component 18',
 'Other', 'Other', None, 'Packaging 2', 'Packaging 3', 'Packaging 4', 'Other', None, 'Packaging 7', None]

other3 = [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None,
 'Component 5', 'Component 6', 'Component 8', 'Component 10', 'Component 11', 'Component 15', 'Component 16', 'Component 17',
 None, 'Component 19', 'Component 20', None, None, None, None, 'Packaging 5', None, None, None]

my_val = [764.7025037682, 922.1573873343998, 1957.1932799999997, 140.7, 1207.8232972546991, 2281.8435614470854, 515.076626462584, 29.182320239999992,
 1121.2985380110642, 1719.9014327173065, 3775.035531264989, 1070.6572813460293, 1674.5794717430463, 30.810666030133756, 422.10395987932935, 56.39659050619138,
 6.3586116808006095, 4.512960708715524, 1.9694367644506894, 1.3722071788772845, 2.7747701218460326, 0.2114258879480555, 0.9394050913579317, 0.04218689368287673,
 45.71662577815401, 8.498568925771194, 0.40354149057007305, 1719.5614117487207, 58.05899316001125, 69.89255424737141, 17.751589750845255, 7.775786234929822,
 3190.0304754954027, 134.42401811928045, 792.7971957632528]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(scope,component,other1,other2,other3,my_val)),
                       columns = ['Scope','Component','Other_label','Layer_2','Layer_3','tCO2e'])


g1 = df.Scope.map(customwrap) #Wrapping the text in the sunburst slices
g2 = df.Component.map(customwrap) #Wrapping the text in the sunburst slices

burst_df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(scope_layer=g1, component_layer=g2, other_layer=df.Other_label, layer_2=df.Layer_2, layer_3=df.Layer_3, my_values=df.tCO2e)) #Creating a new DataFrame that has the wrapped labels

burst_df = burst_df.drop(burst_df[burst_df.my_values == 0].index) #Drop any rows where the value is zero. They do not show up anyway and can cause problems.

fig = px.sunburst(burst_df, path=['scope_layer','component_layer','other_layer','layer_2','layer_3'], values='my_values',
                  maxdepth=2, title='Carbon footprint of 2021')

fig.update_traces(hovertemplate="%{label} <br>%{value:.1f} tCO\u2082e <extra></extra>",insidetextorientation='radial',rotation=90)

fig.show()
```

Hi,

I am creating a sunburst chart in Python using Plotly Express, but the inside text labels are not centred in the 'wedges'.

It seems that the label on the left most wedge is always set to '9 o'clock', and on the right at '3 o'clock'.

Is there a way to adjust it so the label is in the centre of the wedge, but still in a radial orientation so that it is angled radially. As you can see, almost all of the other labels are oriented correctly.

Current format, where the tags (e.g., Packaging 7) are not in the center of the wedge:
[image]

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899149/unwanted-behavior-when-using-insidetextorientation-radial-in-plotly-sunburst) addresses the same issue but in Javascript, not Python

Note: Apologies for the large amount of data. Dummy data may not have represented my issues adequately. The data is subject to change too, so I am looking for a solution that would apply to any data...

Comment: The default should be centered. Please try to add a producible example to be able to help you. You can add some data to your question.

Comment: If you notice, the only off-center labels are those that align with the center vertically. This is by design. If you rotate the dial by let's say -5 degrees, You'd probably see what 'looks' like centered. However, any labels that cross that vertical middle, will be aligned to the middle. By the way, the reference you mentioned in your question was in R, with JS added on. You can add JS onto Python Plotly, as well. (The argument `post_script` is for add-on JS. This argument is in `pio.write_html`, `pio.to_html`, `show` as in `fig.show()`, etc.)

Comment: @Hamzah , I added the data and the rest of the code to make it reproducible. Apologies for the large amount of data. Dummy data may not have represented my issues adequately. Note that I can use plotly.graph_objects if I need to, in which case I can edit the data accordingly.

Comment: @Kat , correct, those that cross the vertical middle are still aligned to the middle. Is there a simpler solution than the one presented with the JS add-on? I am happy to switch to plotly.graph_objects if I need to.

Comment: I believe the text position you want is achieved automatically. `fig.update_traces(hovertemplate="%{label} <br>%{value:.1f} tCO\u2082e <extra></extra>",insidetextorientation='auto')` Please refer to the [references](https://plotly.com/python/pie-charts/#controlling-text-orientation-inside-pie-sectors).

Comment: @r-beginners I would like to keep the 'radial' text orientation. With 'auto' it changes between horizontal and radial text orientations

Comment: Also, I don't think rotation is necessary.

Comment: @r-beginners , the rotation ensures the graph "starts" at 12-o'clock, instead of 3-o'clock.